# Best Continuous Integration system for Clojure

Tags: jenkins, clojure, continuous-integration

I'm currently using Jenkins and Building in Clojure. I was wondering if there was a better CI system for Clojure projects. I know CircleCI is built in Clojure but is [CircleCI the Best CI tool for Clojure](https://circleci.com/)? I read this blog post about [CircleCI's Clojure Library](https://circleci.com/blog/circleci-s-open-source-clojure-library-on-segment/) but wondering what my other options are.

Comment: It's a little hard to define best in a way that you could clearly decide which "best" answer to mark as "correct" on this site. Could you perhaps describe what your doing to build, and ask for options that a) do something you want b) don't do something your current method does. then we could use these to judge answers.

Answer (score 0):

I use CircleCI for a couple of GitHub/Clojure projects and I have found it to be superb.

Can't tell you if it is the best, but I can tell you it was easy to configure, and has worked seamlessly for nearly a year over hundreds of builds.

Easy to integrate with Slack, etc.